# What is the use of reverse key index in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

What is the use of reverse key index in oracle sql

Comment: The  [Oracle Concepts manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/indexiot.htm#CNCPT88844) is your friend!

Comment: A reverse key index when compared to standard index, reverses each byte of the column being indexed while keeping the column order. When the column is indexed in reverse mode then the column values will be stored in an index in different blocks as the starting value differs. Such an arrangement can help avoid performance degradation in indexes where modifications to the index are concentrated on a small set of blocks.

Comment: Ex: SQL> create index stud_ind on student(sno, reverse);

We can rebuild a reverse key index into normal index using the noreverse keyword. 

Ex: SQL> alter index stud_ind rebuild noreverse;

Comment: visit more: http://www.oracleinformation.com/2015/03/reverse-key-index.html

Comment: For Oracle the correct syntax is ` create index stud_ind on student(sno) reverse;`

Comment: From [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:474483191697) (and obvious when you  think about it) a reverse key index is only usable for exact match lookups (e.g. `sno=123`) and cannot be used for range matches (`sno between 123 and 456`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121729/discussion-between-brahmareddy-k-and-tony-andrews).

Answer (score -3):

Any column is having sequence of numbers  then use reverse index ,it will improves the performence.